# Grease Pencil Fill Bucket Tool Functionality with Python Script

Tags: python, grease-pencil

Is it possible to get a similar functionality to the Fill Bucket tool in Grease Pencil with Python? I am developing an add on to automatically matte out Grease Pencil drawings. I need to be able to fill in grease pencil shapes with python commands, similar to if I were using the Fill Bucket Tool.
Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Isn't this the same as your other question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148925/filling-in-grease-pencil-shapes-via-python-script

Comment: In a way, yes. Wanted explain the question a bit better, and find out if the functionality even exists.

Comment: If you need to make an amendment to a question you should use the [edit] link below it instead of asking it again. I suggest either making the two questions more distinctly different or deleting one. Thanks.